# Swap a character with its next character in paragraph

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, function

**I have to swap a specific character appearing in paragraph to its next character.**

let suppose that my paragraph text is:

**My name is andrew. I am very addicted to python and attains very high knowledge about programming.**

Now, my task is to find particular character in paragraph and swap it with the character next to it. Like, I want to swap every character 'a' with its the character next to it. After process my paragraph should look like this:

**My nmae is nadrew. I ma very dadicted to python nad tatians very high knowledge baout progrmaming.**

I would be very thankful if anybody define function for this in python

Comment: What happens if there is a double 'a'?

Comment: What have you tried? Sorry, but this feels more like asking someone to do the task for you, and not a question.

Comment: yeah i have tried.. I have extracted the position of text.. using ***for position,char in enumerate(my_text):
    if char=='a':
 print position***

Comment: also swapping by using:
temp=a[position]
a[position+1]=a[position]
a[position+1]=temp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
>>> import re
>>>>regex = re.compile(r'(a)(\w)')
>>>>text = 'My name is andrew. I am very addicted to python and attains very high knowledge about programming.'
>>> regex.sub(lambda(m) : m.group(2) + m.group(1), text)
'My nmae is nadrew. I ma very dadicted to python nad tatians very high knowledge baout progrmaming.'
```

Explanation:

```
(a)(\w)
```

Matches a, and put it on group 1, then matches another word character put in group 2. Lambda expression for replacement switch these two groups.

If you want to match everything but spaces use :

```
(a)(\S)
```

Comment: what does \w means in Regex??

Comment: word, its equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Comment: and what can we use if some special character appears after 'a' like $, !, ;, %

Comment: if you want to match everything but spaces use \S

Comment: Works for me. Thanks you Rodrigo for answer. I was trying very hard for this from last two days. Regex made this easier. Once again Thanks